# Plot tree with R

Tags: r, plot, tree

from a data.frame (or any other R object type), with 3 Columns: "Node, Parent and text", I'd like to plot a tree with rows from "Node" to "Parent" and "text" as label.

Can anyone suggest a good library to use and example code, if possible.
I've been looking at the igraph library, but all examples I could find plot trees with sequential numbers or letters as nodes and its not simple to set the tree layout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys for all your help, I really appreciate it.
Some extra comments, if you can help further

@md1630, I tried your suggestion but that's not what I'm looking for. The fist code plots the tree with the root on top and the arrows from root to leaf and the second corrects the arrows but inverts the tree. What I'd like is root on top and arrow from leafs to root (I understand that may not be a tree per say - but that's the requirement

[image]

@user20650 your solution looks correct but the image starts to get crowded as the number of nodes increase. Any idea on how to add more space between them?[image]

@math Am I using the function you provided correctly?  I called plot(layout.binary(g)) and got the result on the left. The one on the right is the output of plot(g)

[image]

Comment: You can use `igraph`. Use `graph.data.frame` to create the graph, set edge labels in the `plot` call with `edge.label=E(g)$text` and get a tree layout with `layout.reingold.tilford`

Answer (score 3):

upgrade comment

```
library(igraph)

# some example data
dat <- data.frame(parent=rep(letters[1:3], each=2), 
                  node=letters[2:7], 
                  text=paste0("lab", 1:6))
# create graph
g <- graph.data.frame(dat)

# plot
# layout.reingold.tilford gives a tree structure
# edge and vertx labels can be defined in the plot command or alternatively
# you can add them to the graph via V(g)$name and E(g($label assignments

plot(g, layout = layout.reingold.tilford, 
             edge.label=E(g)$text, vertex.label=paste0("v_lab",1:7))
```

**EDIT** re comment

If you want the direction to go from the leaves towards the root; you can first, get the tree layout coordinates from the more standard tree structure, and then reverse the edges.

```
# get tree layout coords
g <- graph.data.frame(dat)
lay = layout.reingold.tilford(g)

# redraw graph with edges reversed
g2 <- graph.data.frame(dat[2:1], vertices = get.data.frame(g, what="vertices"))

par(mar=rep(0,4), mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g, layout=lay)
plot(g2, layout=lay)
```

[image]

Comment: that's great, the only thing is that the arrows are inverted; so the first line on "dat" is   "parent node text "  "a    b lab1";    and the arrow on the report is flowing from a to b and it should be the other way around. When I tried to implement the change, it scrambled all the layout. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a `tree` with the direction of the edges going from the `leaves` up to the `root` ?

Comment: thanks user. I have another question regarding layout, can you take a look at the edit?

Answer (score 2):

You can use rgraphviz. Here's the code to plot the tree from a dataframe df with columns "Node, Parent and text". I didn't run this on my computer so there may be bugs. But roughly this is the idea:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rgraphviz")
library("Rgraphviz")
#first set up the graph with just the nodes
nodes<- unique(df['Node'])
gR <- new("graphNEL", nodes = nodes, edgemode = "directed")
#add edges for each row in df
    for (j in (1:nrow(df))) {
       gR <- addEdge(df[j,2], df[j,1], gR, 1)
    }
#add text labels
nAttrs <- list()
z <- df['text']
nAttrs$label <- z
#plot
plot(gR, nodeAttrs = nAttrs) #you can specify more attributes here
```

Comment: thanks very much! two things: this code plots the tree upside down (root on the bottom) - do you know how to put it on top? Also the label part doesn't seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: oh sorry, the addEdge function wasn't correct. addEdge is addEdge(from, to, graph, weights). So it should add an edge from parent to node, not the other way around. I just edited my post. It should work now hopefully

Comment: thanks md, I tried that but it still  doesn't work. Take a look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `igraph` to get a network with your data (supposing your dataframe is `dd`):

```
g = graph(t(dd[,2:1]))
V(g)$label = as.character(dd$text)
plot(g, layout=layout.binary)
```

I supposed your root (with no parents) is not in the dataframe, otherwise use `dd[-1,2:1]` instead.

If you want to have a tree, you can easily produce a layout, it is simply a function that takes a graph and return a matrix. For a binary tree :

```
layout.binary = function(graph) {
    layout = c()
    r_vertex = length(V(graph))
    depth = ceiling(log2(r_vertex+1))
    for (ii in 0:(depth-1)) {
        for (jj in 1:min(2^ii, r_vertex)) {
            layout = rbind(layout, c(ii, (2*(jj-1)+1)/(2^(ii+1))))
        }
        r_vertex = r_vertex - 2^ii
    }
    return(layout)
}
```

It will plot an horizontal tree, use `c((2*(jj-1)+1)/(2^(ii+1)), ii)` if you want it to be vertical.

Comment: Thanks math, but simply calling  g = graph(t(c[,2:1])) returns an "cannot create empty graph with negative number of vertices," error; t(c[,2:1])  returns       [,1] [,2]
Parent "A"  "A" 
Node   "B"  "C"

Comment: It is probably because your `Node` and `Parent` columns have characters instead of numbers, use `g=graph(matrix(c(as.factor(dd[,2]), as.factor(dd[,1])), nrow=2, byrow=T))` to fix it. (because the `graph` calls `as.numeric`, and it yields `NA` for a character, but a number for factors)

Comment: yeah but then the as factor plots the factor instead of the string....also Im not sure if Im using the function correctly. Can you take a look at the edit? thanks

Comment: You should use it like in the first piece of code, `V(g)$label=` changes what is displayed in the nodes, even using factors. But this layout function puts `2^n` nodes at each level, so it does not exactly fit your network, see user20650 EDIT which uses the same strategy but with implemented layout function.